# Pankove optical absorption equations: cgs problem?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, units, absorption

I'm embarrassed to be asking this question here, but I've been beating my head against an equation for two weeks and can't get the numbers to work. I'm trying to plug in numbers into Jacque Pankove's "Optical Properties in Semiconductors" equations for optical absorption (equations 3-3 and 3-5). They are given as:

$$\alpha_a(h\nu)=\frac{q^2(2\frac{m_h m_e}{m_h+m_e})^{3/2}}{n c h^2 m_e}(h\nu-E_g)^{1/2} \approx 2\times 10^4 (h\nu-E_g)^{1/2}\;\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$$

and

$$\alpha_f(h\nu)=\frac{4}{3} \frac{q^2(\frac{m_h m_e}{m_h+m_e})^{5/2}}{n c h^2 m_e m_h h\nu}(h\nu-E_g)^{3/2} \approx 1.3\times 10^4\frac{(h\nu-E_g)^{3/2}}{h\nu}\;\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$$

where the approximations assume n = 4 and m_e and m_h are set to the free electron mass. But for the life of me, I can't get the left side prefactors to come out to the right side. I've tried plugging in cgs/Gaussian and SI, and various eV/J/erg combinations, but all are off by orders of magnitude, none of which seem to correspond to a physical constant (c, h, m0, etc.). I've tried converting the full equations to SI using NRL's Plasma Formulary, which does get the units to work out correctly to 1/cm, but the prefactor is still wrong. Even when I just take the ratio of the two prefactors, I should get $(2\times10^4) / (1.3\times10^4)= 1.54$, but instead I get $3\sqrt{2}=4.24$. So there's clearly some kind of conversion factor being assumed for energy or mass or both. What am I missing? Full disclosure: I've never worked in cgs for anything beyond simple mechanics, so it's probably something stupid I'm missing.

Edit: If it helps identify the unit system Pankove is using, the Bohr radius is defined (eqn. 1-12) as $$a=\frac{\hbar^2\epsilon}{q^2 m}$$ which appears to be neither MKS units ($\frac{4\pi\epsilon\hbar^2}{q^2 m}$) nor Gaussian units ($\frac{\hbar^2}{q^2 m}$).

Comment: Can you backtrack in the book to identify units for all the constants mentioned in these formulas?

Comment: Well, Maxwell's equations are in chapter 4 for your inspection.